# C Doubly Linked List read access violation

Tags: c

I am currently creating a planet simulation and having an issue when trying to delete planets if they collide with one another, please see the details below.

I am currently having an issue with deleting elements from my Double Linked List, resulting in a read access violation, stating that one of the elements "was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCB". I am relatively new to C so I believe I am simply missing something somewhere.

Please note that when the remove() method is used without the destroy() method, the error does not occur, it only occurs when the destroy() method is used with/follows the remove() method, and only occasionally at that.

The code is attached below:

```
struct planet *head; //Head of list
struct planet *tail; //Tail of list

struct planet { 
    //Data
    float mass;
    struct planet *next;
    struct planet *prev;
};

planet *removeTail() {
    struct planet* p = tail;
    if (tail) {
        if (head == tail) {
            head = tail = 0;
        }
        else {
            tail = tail->prev;
            p->prev = 0;
            tail->next = 0;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

planet *removeHead() {
    struct planet* p = head;
    if (head) {
        if (head == tail) {
            head = tail = 0;
        }
        else {
            head = head->next;
            p->next = 0;
            head->prev = 0;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

planet *remove(struct planet* p) {//Breaking the tree
    if (p == head) {
        removeHead();
    }
    else if (p == tail) {
        removeTail();
    }
    else {
        p->prev->next = p->next;
        p->next->prev = p->prev;
    }
    return p;
}

planet *destroy(struct planet* p) {
    if (p) {
        if (p != head || p != tail || (!p->next && p->prev)) {
            delete p;
            printf("Deleted\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("Not deleted\n");
            return 0;
        }
     }
 }

for (struct planet *p1 = head; p1 != 0; p1 = p1->next)
{
    for (struct planet *p3 = head; p3 != 0; p3 = p3->next)
        {
            //Collision logic
            if(p1 != p3){
                 if(p1->mass >= p3->mass){
                    destroy(remove(p3)); //Does not cause an error
                    break;
                 }else{
                    destroy(remove(p1)); //Causes the error.
                    break;
                    //Deleting p1 here means the for loop can't move on
                 } 
            }
        }
}
```

I believe I have included all the relevant code above, if you require any further information please let me know. I am also not aware exactly what triggers the error in that sometimes the simulation can remove and delete several nodes without issue, in other cases it can only remove one.

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this should be tagged as opengl because the code sample does not use it.

Comment: There is actually three loops, I have mistakenly only shown two in the above, I'll correct the code now.

I have also removed the opengl tag, my apologies.

Comment: The additional code has been added.

Comment: Are you sure about the logic of `if (p != head || p != tail || (!p->next && p->prev))`? Looks as though it is unlikely to be false with all those `||`. And is the `!` in `!p->next` the wrong side of the parenthesis?

Comment: I don't think it's causing an issue as the delete method runs and is completed successfully. Just some more information to potentially help with the puzzle, when the user hits the '-' key, it calls `destroy(removeTail);`, and that causes no issues at all, and the only two differences I can spot between that case and the case above is that the remove method is different, and it is called within a loop that is iterating through the Linked List it is deleting from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this has an answer, the issue was that the outer for loop was broken within the p3 loop. p1 simply needs to be deleted so that it does not destroy the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The deletion code could be a single function:

```
planet *remove(struct planet* p)
    if (p->prev == NULL) {
        head = p->next;
    }
    else {
        p->prev->next = p->next;
    }

    if (p->next == NULL) {
        tail = p->prev;
    }
    else {
        p->next->prev = p->prev;
    }
    return p;
}
```

And perhaps there should be a `free(p)` somewhere.

Comment: It would make more sense, but the lecturer for the class wants to see several methods included for the LinkedList, including removals for the head and tail. With regards to using `free(p)`, isn't `delete p;` in the `destroy()` method handling that?

Comment: @Alex Not in the C language. There is no `delete`.

Comment: Sorry, you tagged this as C. The function I wrote works for any element of the doubly linked list, but what happens if you to continue to iterate is harder to see. And once you have handed the memory for `p` back to the system, you must not dereference it again (such as in one of the loop controls).

Comment: Sorry, it's confusing, the lecturer for the class wants c++'s `new` and `delete` functions to be used and not c's `malloc()` and so on. I had concerns about my `remove()` method but excluding the `removeHead()` and `removeTail()` they look similar. Could the issue have something to do with the Linked List being modified whilst it's is being iterated through? That's a common issue I have run into with other data structures in Android and Java, but I'm not sure if the same logic carries over to C/C++ or whatever hybrid my lecturer has me doing. Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: You are comparing the mass of every planet with every other planet, including itself? So `if(p1->mass >= p3->mass)` will be true when `p1 == p3` from different loops, all the planets will be removed, and you will end up iterating through invalid pointers?

Comment: Sorry, another piece of code I haven't included. I'll add it in now. The collision detection itself is sound. *Corrected*