# Read Access Violation when looping through LinkedList

Tags: c++

I am creating a planet simulation which makes use of a doubly linked list and several loops to calculate forces, collisions and so on. The issue I am having is a read access violation error when trying to delete a planet due to a collision.

When checking for a collision the smaller of the two planets is deleted, and the way I wrote it is that the smaller planet in the equation can be from the encompassing loop, which if deleted breaks the loop.

A combination of being new to C; staring at the same issue for days now; and that my lecturer for the class is making us use a C/C++ hybrid, is resulting in me struggling to think of an efficient way to fix the issue. Moving the loops out can and has solved the issue, but has a drastic effect on performance of the simulation.

The code can be seen below:

```
struct planet *head; //Head of list
struct planet *tail; //Tail of list

struct planet { 
    //Data
    float mass;
    struct planet *next;
    struct planet *prev;
};

planet *remove(struct planet* p) {//Breaking the tree
    if (p == head) {
        removeHead(); //Method not included in sample due to size and it is sound.
    }
    else if (p == tail) {
        removeTail();//Method not included in sample due to size and it is sound.
    }
    else {
        p->prev->next = p->next;
        p->next->prev = p->prev;
    }
    return p;
}

planet *destroy(struct planet* p) {
    if (p) {
        if (p != head || p != tail || (!p->next && p->prev)) {
            delete p;
            printf("Deleted\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("Not deleted\n");
            return 0;
        }
     }
 }

for (struct planet *p1 = head; p1 != 0; p1 = p1->next)
    {
        for (struct planet *p3 = head; p3 != 0; p3 = p3->next)
            {
                //Collision logic
                if(p1 != p3){
                     if(p1->mass >= p3->mass){
                        destroy(remove(p3)); //Does not cause an error
                        break;
                     }else{
                        destroy(remove(p1)); //Causes the error.
                        break;
                        //Deleting p1 here means the for loop can't move on
                     } 
                }
            }
    }
```

What I am looking for is some advice on how to delete p1 efficiently and without breaking the loop.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and please forgive my less than clean code.

Comment: Your lecturer is teaching C, with the exception of `new` and `delete`. Ugh.

Comment: Apart from the horribly weird combination, why does `destroy` have a return value? All it returns is 0 anyway, might as well not have a return at all?

Comment: Correct, however, for some reason he defaults back to `malloc` for textures...

Comment: Destroy returns 0 as it will be used for a method I am yet to implement. I think.

Comment: I would think destroying `p3` will also cause the error but you are not seeing it. Anyway one way out could be to not use assignment in forloop iteration, change it yourself at the end of loop. You can use some flag/if-else to appropriately move to next item, depending upon you destroyed it or not.

Comment: You say deleting `p1` causes an error but deleting `p3` does not. Well they *both* can cause errors since in both cases you go on to dereference them in the control loop. If suggest you make one pass to establish which are to be deleted, and another pass to delete them. BTW the first nesting is very inefficient: you are testing each planet against each other *twice*, I suggest the first inner loop is `for (struct planet *p2 = p1->next; p2 != 0; p2 = p2->next)`.

Comment: When p3 or p1 is deleted it breaks out of the for loop which stops the error for p3. My fault for forgetting it in the code sample. I'll take a look at using flag/if-else.

Comment: This is the second time you have [asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500941/c-doubly-linked-list-read-access-violation) and you are still not posting the code you have used!

Comment: Sorry Vane, I made a mess of the last question so am currently waiting for it to be deleted by the moderator. Discovering the actual issue is what prompted the new question. There's a lot of maths in the loops that I have removed just to make the code sample smaller, would you rather I include it? Just to make the use of the loops clear?

Comment: You don't need all the math but you do need all the flow control.

Comment: I have removed the second loop as it has no affect on the collision and or removal of the planet.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not allowed to use smart pointers?

Comment: Unfortunately the project has to be coded in C with the exception of `new` and `delete`. I believe someone edited the original question and removed the C tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking out of the inner loop when `p1` is destroyed, will not break the outer loop, where `p1` is dereferenced by the loop control, after it was deleted.

You can avoid it with code perhaps like this. I don't like using `for` loops with a linked list, and the `while` makes it easy to set up the next link.

```
struct planet *p1link, *p3link;

p1 = head;
while(p1 != NULL) {
    p1link = p1->next;              // collect next link now
    p3 = p1->next;                  // avoid detecting B-A as well as A-B
    while(p3 != NULL) {
        p3link = p3->next;          // collect next link now
        //Collision logic
        if(p1->mass >= p3->mass){
            destroy(remove(p3));
        } else {
            destroy(remove(p1));
        }
        p3 = p3link;                // next
    }
    p1 = p1link;                    // next
}
```

However the whole concept is flawed, because the `p3` you delete might be the next `p1` planet. So I suggest including a struct member `pending` and you make another parse of the list afterwards, to remove dead planets.

Comment: I'm aware, trying to find an efficient solution for deleting it whilst still moving on to the next planet.

Comment: @Alex I have extended the answer.